# animate width : content goes out when width zero

Tags: jquery, css

I have red and blakc divs; when I hover over the parrent the red div should appear  by changing the width to the real width! but the problem is when the width is 0px; the content is shown! Could you please help me to solve it!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/pTU3L/)

```
 $('#container').mouseover(function(){
$('#red').stop(true,true).animate({ width: '110px'}, 100);
})
$('#container').mouseout(function(){
$('#red').stop(true,true).animate({ width: '0px'}, 100);
})
```

updated:

[Solved Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/pTU3L/4)
But now while the red div resizes to the actual width the text "watch video" goes to two lines! How to force it to be in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pTU3L/2/

added 
`overflow:hidden`

to the #red div.
check the updated fiddle

Comment: Thanks! you solved it; but look at the time it is resizing the world goes to the next line and then comes up to the actual line! any idea to solve this too? http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/pTU3L/4/

Comment: you could set a "line-height" to the height of the #red div, to center it vertically